# Attaching event handlers on the fly

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm attaching an event handler to a table cell. The table is generated after clicking on the search button. The search button also generates a link, which when clicked, opens a modal popup that has another table in it. The table in the modal popup should also have the same event handler attached to its cells.

Is it all right to do this:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.cell-with-action', function(e){
    var action = $(this).find('.action');

    if(e.type == 'mouseenter'){
        //do something
    }
    else{
        //do something else
    }
});
```

or is it better to attach it when the search button and link button are clicked? Would it make a difference to do this:

```
$('.table-with-action').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.cell-with-action', function(e){
    var action = $(this).find('.action');

    if(e.type == 'mouseenter'){
        //do something
    }
    else{
        //do something else
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between the 2 options (for your question, not your code) is that the first will load when the document loads compared to when you click the search button.

The benefit of doing this when the document loads is that you don't have to check whether it has been loaded before you attached it, as you would when you do it on search click because you would then get a new event attached for each click & so you would be calling the same function multiple times when the event is fired.

If you have a page that loads quickly (i.e. not very big/dynamic) then it makes sense to use the first option. Otherwise use the second IMO.

As for your code: The first snippet attaches to the document whereas the second attaches to the table. So depending on how many of these tables you have you might end up with conflicts. Also with the more specific selector `.table-with-action` the event doesn't have to bubble as far up the DOM tree before it is actioned as it would for $(document). More importantly, events on unrelated elements don't reach the handler at all, which means that jQuery doesn't have to filter unrelated events (as noted by Jan).

You might also want to return false or use e.stopPropagation or e.stopDefault depending on what your requirements are.

Comment: "the event doesn't have to bubble as far up the DOM tree" - more importantly, events on unrelated elements don't reach the handler at all, instead of being filtered out by jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

You should be fine with your first example, however you may want to add the event handlers to the `<body>` element rather than the document, and qualify the class with an element type (ie: 'table td.cell-with-action') for performance reasons.

Comment: Why would attaching to `body` be any better than attaching to `document`?

Comment: Why would `table td.cell-with-action` be any faster than `.cell-with-action`? The browser has to traverse upwards if you do this!

Comment: The browser has to look through every single type of element to find any that match `.cell-with-action` unless you qualify it with an element type. Including `table td` beforehand ensure that it only looks in tables for table cells with that class name, and can be noticeably faster depending on the number of elements in your DOM.

Comment: When you do event delegation, the browser does not look for elements which match the selector to see if the event target is one of them. Instead, the selector is tested against the event target and its ancestors.

Comment: Even when you're searching for elements, `.class` is much faster than `el.class` because the browser holds a list of elements for each class that it can hand out directly. It doesn't have to traverse the entire document.

Comment: so having a more specific selector would actually make processing longer?